# MySql - INSERT returns 0 rows affected

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, insert-into, mysql-5.6

I'm trying to run the following command in the command line terminal of MySql, on my backup server:

**Table Schema** :

```
CREATE TABLE `cadveiculoequip` (
  `idveiculoequip` VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
  `idveiculo` VARCHAR(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idequipamento` VARCHAR(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `datainstalacao` DATE DEFAULT NULL,
  `datadesinstalacao` DATE DEFAULT NULL,
  `idchkheader` VARCHAR(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ID` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastupdate` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `primario` INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `mapeia_sombra` INT(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `tec_responsavel` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `km_rodado` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `situacao` INT(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `teclado` VARCHAR(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rfid` VARCHAR(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idsatelite` VARCHAR(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `telemetria` VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idosdes` VARCHAR(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idveiculoequip`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AVG_ROW_LENGTH=129;
```

**Query is** :

```
INSERT INTO `cadveiculoequip`  (`idveiculoequip`,`idveiculo`,`idequipamento`,`datainstalacao`,`datadesinstalacao`,`idchkheader`,`ID`,`lastupdate`,`primario`,`mapeia_sombra`,`tec_responsavel`,`km_rodado`,`situacao`,`teclado`,`rfid`,`idsatelite`,`telemetria`,`idosdes`)
VALUES ('IGORM','6788103A-8109-430C-A131-9FBBAF6D01F3','8abef011-c107-11df-b983-68b5558ab3e2','2018-02-21',NULL,'2CA923B6-60E9-42CF-BCFB-4BA238263079',4257329,'2018-02-21 08:44:51',1,0,'IGORM','0',1,NULL,NULL,NULL,'',NULL);
```

After execute the command, i just receive the message **"0 rows affected"**.

Okay, so what's the problem..? I have executed the exactly same command in my development server (identical to backup server) the command has executed successfully, besides has returned **"1 rows affected"**.

I discard the idea of ​​being a **MySQL Error 1064..** Does anyone know what it could be?

(Sorry about the bad english, I'm kind of rusty... hehehe)

**Edit:**
[Table 'cadveiculoequip'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sT2K6.png)

Comment: can you add the schema of the table, too?

Comment: I added the image..

Comment: Have you checked for `idveiculoequip = 'IGORM'` already being in table? Also can you add the schema in a code block so we can try it in sqlfiddle?

Comment: So.. Yup, i already checked this.. The value 'IGORM' is unique.. And about the sqlfiddle, this would be a problem. There's too many tables. I know it's better, but i can't do that too.. And the Foreign Keys, they exist in the "mother" tables..

Comment: You only need to add the schema of the table cadveiculoequip

Comment: See if I made it right ..
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c860c/2

Comment: Yes, the fiddle is right. I have tried it through there and also on my own sandbox, and it didn't return with `0 rows affected`. I'm not able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: sorry to ask it again, but I don't understand what do you mean with "the value 'IGORM' is unique". What's the output of `select count(1) from cadveiculoequip where idveiculoequip = 'IGORM' `?

Comment: It's ok Cemal. Thanks..

Comment: senape, the output is 0. With unique, I intended to say there isn't other register with the same value 'IGORM'.